# sectionIndexTitles Mapping is not working correctly

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uikit

I have this data Struct in my iOS project which has a tableView populated from a sqlite3 database.

```
struct Song {
    let id: Int
    let songTitle: String
    let movieName: String
    let songSinger: String
    let musicDirector: String
    let songLyrics: String
    let movieReleased: String
    let songScale: String
    let leadCast: String
    let songTrivia: String
    let scaleURL: String
    let youtubeURL: String
    let lyricsURL: String
}
```

This is how I am creating my sectionIndexTitlesArray:

```
var movieSet = Set<String>()
for song in songList {
    movieSet.insert(song.movieName)
            
    let firstLetter = String(song.movieName.prefix(1))
    if !firstLetters.contains(firstLetter) {
        firstLetters.append(firstLetter)
    }

    uniqueMovies = Array(movieSet)
    uniqueMovies.sort()
    sectionIndexTitles = firstLetters.sorted()
}
```

This is how I create number of sections:

```
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    if isSearching == true {
        return 1
    } else {
        return uniqueMovies.count
    }     
}
```

This is the func for number of rows in section

```
if isSearching == true {
    return filteredSongs.count
} else {
        let sectionTitle = uniqueMovies[section]
        let sectionData = songList.filter { $0.movieName == sectionTitle }
        return sectionData.count
}
```

This is the func for titleForHeaderSection

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    if isSearching == true {
        return nil
    } else {
        return "  "+uniqueMovies[section]
    }
}
```

This is the func for sectionIndexTitles

```
func sectionIndexTitles(for tableView: UITableView) -> [String]? {
    if isSearching == true {
        return nil
    }  else {
        return sectionIndexTitles
    }
}
```

This is the func for sectionForSectionIndexTitles

```
func sectionForSectionIndexTitle(title: String, atIndex index: Int) -> Int {
    return sectionIndexTitles.firstIndex(of: title)!
}
```

The problem is that when I tap the letter from right side index titles, it does not jump to corresponding section. Instead it jumps to section that matches with index of sectionTitles. For e.g. If I tap "D", it jumps to 4th sectionHeader. What is wrong?

Comment: I have also tried this for sectionForSectionIndexTitle, but it gives same behaviour.

'func sectionForSectionIndexTitle(title: String, atIndex index: Int) -> Int {
       return firstLetters.firstIndex(of: title) ?? 0
}'

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you can have more than one section that starts with the same letter. So you may have 5 values in `uniqueMovies` that all start with the letter "A", 7 values that start with the letter "B", 3 that start with the letter "C", etc.

If the user taps the letter A you want to go to section 0.
For the letter B you want to go to section 5.
For the letter C you want to go to section 12. And for the letter D you want to go to section 15, etc.

So your implementation of `sectionForSectionIndexTitle` can't simply find the index of the letter in `sectionIndexTitles`. You need to find the first index in `uniqueMovies` that starts with the letter.

```
func sectionForSectionIndexTitle(title: String, atIndex index: Int) -> Int {
    return uniqueMovies.firstIndex { $0.hasPrefix(title) } ?? 0
}
```

Comment: Hi, 

That didn't work. It still does the same behaviour.

Comment: I don't see how my solution can have the same behavior as your solution. They act on completely different data and give a different result. Update your question with your `numberOfRows` and `cellForRowAt`. And add a screenshot of your table view.

Comment: I am unable to post code in comment. It is long enough to fit in comments.

Here's the link to my codes as...

[CodeShare](https://codeshare.io/Ad9YlN). The link will expire in 24hrs.

Comment: Update your question with all relevant details, including the screenshot.